# PHP change directory according to parameter ($GET from url)

Tags: php, php-include

I try to run project and get `localhost:8000/fishes.php` and then change it to `localhost:8000/fishes.php?fish=pike` (or trout).

I have directories on same project `/info/pike` (or trout) and in these directories there is `info.txt` where first line has fish latin name and second line has average size.

My question is, How can I get text from that file to "site". Code doesn't include html-code, I don't have the code right now with me. But it is fine and runs normally.

Thanks

```
   <?php
        $species = $_GET["fish"];
        if (file_exists("info.txt")) {
        $array = explode("/n", file_get_contents('$species/info.txt'));
        $name = $array[0];
        $size = $array[1];
        } else {
        }

        global $name;
        global $size;

        ?>


         <h1><?php$name?> (<?php$size?>)</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Markup, you're opening the php tag, and calling a variable. This variable is not actually printing to the STDOUT. You have a few options:

```
<?php echo $name; ?>
```

or

```
<?php print $name; ?>
```

or if you have shorttags enabled

```
<?=$name;?>
```

Comment: I try it when i get from work. This answer is so simple, why i didn´t realise it. Thanks, i will report how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `echo` or `print` for variables.

```
 <?php
        $name = '';
        $size = '';
        $species = $_GET["fish"];
        if (file_exists("info.txt")) {
            $array = explode("/n", file_get_contents('$species/info.txt'));
            $name = $array[0];
            $size = $array[1];
        } else {
            //Code for Else
        }

        //global $name; //No Need of Globals if you have html in same file
        //global $size; //No Need of Globals if you have html in same file

        ?>


         <h1><?php echo $name?> (<?php echo $size?>)</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use double quotes in "$species/info.txt"

Answer (score 0):

if you server support short tags you can:

```
<h1><?=$name;?> (<?=$size;?>)</h1>
```